# Homogeneous Space of Hyperbolic Space

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry, book-recommendation, hyperbolic-geometry

I'm studying some hyperbolic geometry, but I'm new to the area. In the book I'm reading, from Jensen's "Surfaces in Classical Geometries", the term homogeneous space of hyperbolic space appeared.

Could someone help me with some reference/book about explaining this right?

Comment: To understand homogeneous spaces, you need to start by understanding (at least to some extent) Lie groups. I don't know what your background is. You might start with M.L. Curtis's *Matrix Groups*. At a much more sophisticated level is J. Wolf's *Spaces of Constant Curvature*.